# Insert into mysql database rather than printing

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I'm pretty new at  working with Python, and I'm looking to collect Twitter data into my MySQL database for a project. I have my script for collecting data from this tutorial:

```
import re
from re import sub
import time
import cookielib
from cookielib import CookieJar
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen
import difflib

cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]

keyWord = 'nyc'
startingLink = 'https://twitter.com/search/realtime?q='

# begin loop

def main():

    oldTwit = []
    newTwit = []
    while 1 < 2:
        try:
            sourceCode = opener.open ('https://twitter.com/search/realtime?q='+keyWord+'&src=hash').read()
            splitSource = re.findall (r'  <p class="js-tweet-text tweet-text">(.*?)</p>',sourceCode)
            for item in splitSource:
                #print item
                print ''
                print ''
                print '                           '
                aTweet = re.sub(r'<.*?>', '',item)
                print aTweet
                newTwit.append(aTweet)

            comparison = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, newTwit, oldTwit)
            howSim = comparison.ratio()
            print '##############'
            print howSim

            oldTwit = [None]
            for eachItem in newTwit:
                oldTwit.append(eachItem)

            newTwit = [None]

            time.sleep(howSim*10)

        except Exception, e:
            print str(e)
            print 'errored in the main try'
            time.sleep(555)

main()
```

Which provides me with the Tweets I want to collect (I'm not really looking to analyze this data, I'm more experimenting with collecting data automatically using python to connect to my db.)

I also have my database connected using MySQLdb and am able to add content to my database using a simple insert statement:

```
import MySQLdb
db=MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1",user="root",passwd="",db="twitinfo")
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO tweets(text) VALUES ('?')"
cursor.execute(sql)
db.commit()
```

So my question is how can I 'replace' print with my insert statement, and what do I need to add to make my values the tweet text? I have searched high and low and I'm not finding anything helpful on this. I also tried myself, but as a Python newbie, trying to guess the syntax for this is like finding a needle in a haystack.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL you show is inserting a string consisting of a single question mark into the DB.  You need to use `VALUES(?)` to specify a placeholder for a value, and you need to pass a value to the execute function for it to insert, perhaps like this:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO tweets(text) VALUES (?)"
value = "Apoplectic Fits"
cursor.execute(sql, value)
```

You need to add the import line to your Python at the top andconnect to the DB outside the loop.  You can probably put the cursor create line outside the loop.  Inside the loop, you use your tweet message in place of `value`.

---

After reading the documentation for [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) (a recommended practice when using a new module), you need to use `%s` for the placeholder, not `?`.

If you want to insert the data in the variable `aTweet`, then:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO tweets(text) VALUES (%s)"
cursor.execute(sql, aTweet)
```

Untested.  In theory, there's no difference between theory and practice; in practice, there is.

Comment: SQL uses question marks as placeholders.  You'll need to find the documentation for the [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) module to see whether what I've guessed is how you execute the SQL with a value is correct; it looks like I'm close enough to right.  There's one oddball feature; the examples at least use `%s` instead of `?` to indicate where values are to be placed.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks, that was helpful. Can I use the same variable I used to print? I added it to the insert command:

    main()

    sql = "INSERT INTO parse(text) VALUES (aTweet)"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()

    cursor.execute(sql)

    db.commit()

I think Im on the right track, I'm not getting a syntax error and the script is still pulling in tweets after the edit, but my table still returns 0 rows. http://screencast.com/t/vwCFOZWL